# How does google do?

Tags: html

How does Google do the little animation that replace the Google logo every day?

I know the whole world lost almost 5 million hours playing Pacman at work last year (but it was worth it :D). But I am still very impressed by these little interactive games.

I was wondering what technology google is using to have an animation that perfect on their home page?

Comment: Get the firebug extension on firefox, or use the web developer tools on Chrome/IE and you can look at the javascript they use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pacman one was some fairly fancy JavaScript, so I'd imagine most of them are done in a similar manner. The Les Paul one yesterday was JavaScript and embedded a SWF file to play the sounds.

Comment: Actually [it was a combination of JavaScript, HTML5 Canvas, CSS, Flash and other tools like Google Font API, goo.gl and App Engine](http://www.unthinkable.biz/home/article/2515/the-google-doodle-evolves-and-it%5Cs-all-thanks-to-les-paul).

Answer (score 1):

They most likely use HTML5 and JavaScript. But you could acheive the same with Flash.